# springboot security and weblogic interplay

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, weblogic

I have working springboot app, using authorization declared as

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/metrics/**").hasRole(MONITORING_ROLE)
...
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
```

and using InMemoryUserDetailsManager, just to get things going right now.

Now I'm trying to deploy to weblogic...

IIUC springboot2 won't start up(at least I don't know how) on weblogic 12.1.X and due to weblogic bug, spring security is ignored and everything is permitted.

If I'm seeing things right springboot2 does start on 12.2.X, but (due to weblogic bug?) spring security is ignored, and rules are evaluated according to weblogic configuration. Trying to log in as used configured in springboot locks weblogic for too many unsuccessful attempts to log in, meaning, that weblogic security is in play.

Can anyone comment or provide some details how spring-security and weblogic 12.2 should work? I can define login-config, security-role, and security-constraint, but in that case I don't know how spring-security will deal with that ... theoretically I could remove spring security altogether somehow and do everything via weblogic just as in J2EE. Anyways, any hints how you did that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I found this demo, which covers this scenario:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/5.0.x/samples/javaconfig/preauth

plus you probably want to set in your weblogic.xml following:

```
  <security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    <principal-name>admin</principal-name>
  </security-role-assignment>
```